# Deploy a dynamic report

Tags: wolfram-cloud

What does it take to deploy a [report](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AutomatedReports.html) to the Wolfram Cloud? I would like to deploy *the generated notebook* (not the notebook with the slots) to a public URL so my customer can access it. Every time the URL is accessed the data within the slots should be updated. All of this works on my desktop but I don't see the documentation regarding the deployment of the dynamic report.

Comment: I'm very interested in this as well. Maybe if you add some example code to the question to better explain what is working and not it will help get some answers.

Comment: Not sure it has something to do with code. In fact I'm pretty sure it's not Mathematica (code) but something on the level of the cloud. The report gets created in Mathematica (ie. a new notebook is opened as part of the desktop app) while as an online (refreshable) report it should simply be renewed, much like an interpreted webserver page.
The business model they opened up (or tried to) is not there yet. Much like (m)any other software, it'll take version 2.

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen, unrelated to this Q but, in 1001-graphs, did you build the London Underground map? That's nice.

Comment: @alancalvitti Nice of you saying that, thx. The London map ain't mine and is available in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/LondonUnderground.html).